# CASIA face anti-spoofing database

Tags: computer-vision, dataset, face-recognition, spoofing

Does anyone know where I can download CASIA face anti-spoofing database?

This dataset was release with the following [paper](http://www.cbsr.ia.ac.cn/users/jjyan/zhang-icb2012.pdf).

PS.: I tried several links, the URL was removed and there was no response.

Comment: Hi. Did you get the dataset? I actually need it for a project too.

Comment: There you go: https://bitbucket.org/datasets/database-casia-fasd/src/master/
This repository may be available only temporary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually found the dataset:
https://bitbucket.org/datasets/database-casia-fasd/src/master/

Comment: How did you access this ? It says to login from another account.

Comment: broken link, not accessible

Answer (score 2):

There is the CASIA dataset (http://biometrics.idealtest.org/findTotalDbByMode.do?mode=Face)
Try using VPN to access the site, register and then wait.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real dataset link available, you have to sign a release agreement and send it to a certain link, the agreement can be found here: http://www.cbsr.ia.ac.cn/english/FASDB_Agreement/Agreement.pdf

If by any chance you do find a link that points to the dataset kindly link it to me as well since i havent been able to get a response from the dataset owners